# typeorm self reference one to many count

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Hello this is my **comment.entity.ts**:

```
@Entity()
export class Comment extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column()
  email: string;

  @Column({ type: 'text' })
  body: string;

  @Column()
  type: CommentTypeEnum.POST | CommentTypeEnum.COMMENT;

  @Column({ type: 'boolean', default: false })
  has_parent: boolean;

  @ManyToMany(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.children)
  parent: Comment;

  @OneToMany(() => Comment, (comment) => comment.parent)
  children: Comment[];
}
```

As you see i have self referencing with one to many relation.

I fetch my data like this:

```
  const query = Comment.createQueryBuilder('comment');



    query.andWhere('comment.has_parent = false');

    const comments = await query.orderBy('created_at', 'DESC').getMany();
```

I wanna add children count to the result, i don't know how to do it.

Comment: So, if I understood correctly, you want to obtain all ```Comment```(s) where ```has_parent``` is ```false``` and also count how many ```children``` *this* entity has?

Comment: @CarloCorradini yes man

Answer (score 0):

it will fetch like this and it's work for me.

query.loadRelationCountAndMap('comment.childrenCount','comment.children')

Comment: ```query.loadRelationCountAndMap('comment.children', 'comment.children')``` gaves me error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'referencedColumn' of undefined.